# Python Regular expression -matching repeating pattern in one shot

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (col1 decimal(10,2),col2 char(20))
```

From this query String i want to get each of the column details (ie, col1 decimal(10,2) and col2 char(20) etc ) as a list in a single group(#anynumber) call.
currently what i'am doing is given below :

```
columnResult = re.match(r"^CREATE(\s\w+\s*){1,}\((\w+)\s(\S+),\s*(\w+)\s(\S+)",line)
    if columnResult == None:
        pass
    else:
        print("column = ",columnResult.group(2),",",columnResult.group(4))
        print("type = ",columnResult.group(3),", ",columnResult.group(5))
```

Instead of repeating (\w+)\s(\S+) for each column ,how can i match all repeating column details in one shot?
Please help

Comment: what is your exact expected outcome for the example string?

Comment: no matter how many column details are there i want them to be printed on screen.

Comment: Actually i want to print them in the following way :- column name = col1 ,type=decimal, length=10 and precision=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Regex: `(?:(?<=, )|(?<=\(|,))(\w+) (\w+)(?:\((\d+)(?:,(\d+))?\))?`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JuoCPN/3)

Comment: Hi its working perfectly for CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (col1 decimal(10,2),col2 char(20)) statements..what if the statement is like CREATE TABLE HIVE_TABLE(foo INT, bar STRING,cat INT) . ie ,without the 'if not exist' .can you please modify the regex so that it will work for both kind of statements?

Comment: @c0der, I've updated the regex (and demo) to handle the new requirement.

Comment: for python it is showing "(?<= A lookbehind assertion has to be fixed width
) A lookbehind assertion has to be fixed width" error